# Adding extra parts to a model

Tags: modeling, mesh

How can i add this part onto my mesh without adding a separate part.

[image]

Comment: Extrude it? That row of faces fits perfectly as a starting point.

Comment: Hello :). Please add some details about what you tried so far and where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: Also, maybe a little more info about why you don't want to add a separate part.

Comment: I decided to make it a separate part thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

As Nascent Space says, you can extrude that part, then flatten it on the Y axis:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know that but when I shade smooth it and more verts it doesn’t look right. I also need the inside of that part to be empty

Comment: so maybe show what you've done so far so that we see the precise problem you're struggling with, or even share your file (the one with your extrusion attempt and fail)

Comment: Could always mark the edges sharp to fix the normals.

Comment: Will keep in mind to try sharp edges next time Thankyou so much